# How to change the color of a transparent background image's text in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I have This Image

[quran image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoNeK.png)

And I want it to be something like this

[quran image dark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMj7p.png)

Is that possible to do in react native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it up in View and add background color style.

```
<View style={styles.imageContainer}>
{...image here}
</View>
```

and

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    imageContainer: {
        backgroundColor: 'blue'
    }
})
```

Comment: That will change the background color to blue but the text in the image will remain black

Comment: Then make the image SVG. and use react native svg module to change the color of the svg image. https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a way to do this with png images all you have to do is

```
<Image style={{ tintColor: "any color",}} />
```